# If $\sum a_n$ converges, does $\sum a_n / 2^n$ converge as well?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, summation

If $\sum a_n$ converges, does $\sum \dfrac{a_n}{2^n}$ converge as well?

I can't use differential or integral calculus for this.

Answer (score 6):

The series $\sum a_n$ converges so

$$\exists n_0\in\Bbb N\;|\; \forall n\ge n_0,\quad |a_n|\le 1$$
so
$$\exists n_0\in\Bbb N\;|\; \forall n\ge n_0,\quad \frac{|a_n|}{2^n}\le 
\frac1{2^n}$$
and we conclude the convergence of the desired series by comparison with the geometric convergent series $\sum\frac1{2^n}$.

Comment: It might even be easier to bound $\sum a_n/2^n$ by $\max a_n \sum 1/2^n$.

Comment: $\sup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} a_n \sum \frac{1}{2^n}$ is probably a bit more accurate expression

Comment: I think the way it is written in the answer is the most simple and accurate, and way enough to answer the question. +1

Comment: An upper bound isn't sufficient since $a_n$ isn't necessary positive.

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't have enough reputation to add comments I will write it as an answer. Couldn't we just use Abel's Test for convergences? (see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_test)

In terms of this test:

$\sum{\frac{1}{2^n}}$ is $b_n$. It is true that $b_1\geq b_2 \geq b_3 \geq... \geq 0$
Also, it is upper bounded by $1$.

And $\sum{a_n}$ is convergents. That is given.

So by this test also $\sum {a_n*b_n}$ is also convergents.